# JQuery document.ready firing multiple times in IE7 only

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm working with jQuery (v 1.7.1) and need the ui code I'm running to work in IE7. No problem in all modern browsers, and IE8 is fine too.

The issue seems to be that document ready is firing multiple times, and causing a performance issues. This also appears to be an issue across various pages on the site, with varying levels of JS code complexity. I have read that exceptions can cause this behaviour, but I do not believe exceptions are the issue (verified with some global exception catching code).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    alert('doc ready');

    do stuff....
});
```

The above code results in me seeing the 'doc ready' alert many times, before the UI freezes up.

Is this a known issue in jQuery and is there a way to remedy for IE7?

Thanks

Update... trying to isolate the issue, I've tested with the simplest page possible, this simple page does not reproduce the issue...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test JQUery IE7</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            alert('doc ready...');

        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've come across this before when there were broken images on the page.  If the URL points somewhere were there's no image it loads the default page of the site.  Bit of a longshot but it's worth checking, regardless of the problem.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle that "won't work correctly" in your IE7?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually $(window).resize function that appears to fire more frequently in IE7. It could of course be that IE7 just struggled more with running the UI orientated JS on each event.

Setting up a timer / interval to limit the frequency that the event was actioned on solved the problem